# Is it possible to do server side validation from google sponsored html?

Tags: java, javabeans

Can I call `javabean` action from an external html. And is it possible to return response to that html form java action bean?

Answer (score 0):

In order to send an HTTP request to you code from somewhere, you need to write some web server to listen for requests. Then, when the request is received, you will be able to call any method you have and return some result in response.

Here is a tutorial where you can read more about web servers and clients in Java: http://www.journaldev.com/1854/java-web-application-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: how to do server side validation of external html form ?

Comment: What do you want to validate?

Comment: to check email address exist in database or not.

Comment: Seems I now understand what you want. See my updated answer.

Comment: No, i m asking that...is it possible to return reposnse to external html that is outside the appliction from java action bean class?

Comment: I need more information about what you've already used and written in order to help. If you already receive a request, then of course you can return a response.

Comment: i m try to hit a site url from an external resource i.e an html which is outside the application.then how can i return response of action bean to html. suppose i have a form on a html file from where i m calling action bean of some other site in order to insert form values into database of site.i have email field in form if email entered through the form already exist into database, then how i would know on html page that email already present.

Comment: Consider using javascript to send a request and parse response.